# uses of Riemannian geometry for questions not related to Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Poincaré conjecture (whose formulation does not make use of notions from Riemannian geometry: "Every simply connected, closed 3-manifold is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere") was eventually proved using considerations from Riemannian geometry.

In Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_geometry) one finds a long list of results related to Riemannian geometry, however for these results usually either the assumptions or the conclusion of the theorem use notions from Riemannian geometry.

What other questions, besides Poincaré conjecture, whose formulation does not refer to notions from Riemannian geometry, were solved  applying, as one of the means, Riemannian geometry considerations?

**EDIT** I have added the formulation of Poincaré conjecture after a comment which questioned the claim that Poincaré conjecture did not involve Riemannian geometry.

**EDIT** I tried to make the formulation of the question clearer, and to narrow its scope omitting the "metaconsiderations" part.

Comment: Why did the Poincare conjecture not involve Riemannian geometry ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde "Every simply connected, closed 3-manifold is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere." - where do you see here Riemannian geometry?

Comment: Because it was always a special case of Thurston's geometrization conjecture, which involved Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @DietrichBurde " it was always a special case of Thurston's geometrization conjecture" - reference? In the famous Smale's list of problems for the 21-st century, Poincaré conjecture is Problem n. 2. Thurston geometrization conjecture is not mentioned.

Comment: It seems that the criterion to "not involve Riemannian geometry" is prone to subjective application, based on the discussion and criticism by the OP.  Perhaps a narrower question, involving a more objective criterion, would improve on this.

Comment: @JohnDonn: Dietrich's point is that, put in its right context, the Poincare conjecture is absolutely related to Riemannian geometry. But I agree: the fact that it was not *originally* stated in the context of the geometrization conjecture makes this connection it interesting and exciting.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 4):

Here are two suggestions:

1. [Morse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) is a central tool in analyzing the topological structure of manifolds. A key step in the theory is studying the gradient flow of a Morse function, which requires a Riemannian metric to define.
2. [Donaldson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donaldson%27s_theorem) says that if $M$ is a smooth, simply connected, compact $4$-manifold with definite intersection form, then the intersection form of $M$ can be diagonlized over the integers. Since many simply connected topological $4$-manifolds have non-diagonalizable definite intersection forms, this leads to the conclusion that such $4$-manifolds have no smooth structures. This purely topological theorem was proved by studying the space of [instantons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton#Mathematics) on the manifold, which require a Riemannian metric to define.

Answer (score 2):

For 1, positive mass theorem can be one of the examples. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_energy_theorem) is some information about positive mass theorem. Schoen and Yau used the minimal surface to prove the positive mass theorem, which is originally a problem in general relativity.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer, since the reference you give says: "positive energy theorem (more commonly known as the positive mass conjecture in differential geometry) states that, assuming the dominant energy condition, the mass of an **asymptotically flat spacetime** is non-negative" - so the formulation makes an explicit reference to (pseudo) Riemannian geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example: the fundamental group $\pi_1 S$ of a closed oriented surface $S$ of genus $\ge 2$ is a [word hyperbolic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) in the sense of Gromov.

The outline of the proof goes like this. $S$ has a Riemannian metric of constant curvature $-1$. Its universal covering space is therefore a complete, simply connected Riemannian surface of constant curvature $-1$. Every such space is isometric to the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$. The group $\pi_1 S$ therefore acts on $\mathbb{H}^2$ by a cocompact, isometric deck transformation action. By the [theorem of Milnor and Svarc](https://392c.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/thesvarc-milnor-lemma/), the group $\pi_1 S$ with its (finitely generated) word metric is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{H}^2$. The metric space $\mathbb{H}^2$ is a Gromov hyperbolic space. Gromov hyperbolicity is a quasi-isometry invariant, and therefore $\pi_1 S$ with its word metric is a Gromov hyperbolic space. By definition, that means $\pi_1 S$ is word hyperbolic.

Indeed the entire study of word hyperbolic groups was motivated by the study of complete Riemannian manifolds with negative sectional curvature bounded away from zero. This study is a hugely successful enterprise which obtains group theoretic analogues of theorems about negatively curved manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I took a look into "Lecture notes on Geometric Group Theory" by Alessandro Sisto, where there is a list of properties of hyperbolic groups such as: exponential growth, linear time algorithm for the word problem which are easier for me to grasp. Is there such easily stated property of π1(S) which was not known before the theorem you cite was published, and of which it is a corrolary? Was there a question in the literature preceding the appearance of this  theory, on which the theory had a notable impact?

Comment: @JohnDonn: The same paper in which Milnor first proved his theorem that I stated is the paper in which he also proved that $\pi_1(M)$ has exponential growth, for all fundamental groups of compact manifolds $M$ with Riemannian metrics of negative sectional curvature. Other applications, e.g. word problem applications, came later, particularly with the theory of automatic groups which arose around 1990.

Comment: Those word problem applications were known for a surface from the time of Dehn, but the generalization to all such $M$ came only after the emergence of word hyperbolicity and automaticity.